# MS Stack: How to match Local Development Environment to Server Environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

So I'm fairly new to the MS Stack Development world and facing problems with having different local development environment vs the server environment(I assume it was same, and boy was I wrong).

My setup is a Windows 7 64bit using Visual Studio 2012(IIS7.5), and the server is MS Server 2012 (IIS8).

The MS Server 2012 doesn't recognize the way I get Active Directory user Login and also the way I use SQLDataSource in asp.net.

I'm thinking it be could the way I setup the server? Or is my coding doesn't work from IIS7.5 to IIS8? There could be so many things that could go wrong. I could use some direction on this.

My current app that uses:

```
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
            givenName = userPrincipal.GivenName;
            login = userPrincipal.SamAccountName;
```

And it's throwing an error in the server.

Also in the web.config there's tons of errors the in the server and every error resolved leads to another error.

Now it's giving this error:
    The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

And that's after fixing another error with this:

```
<clear/>
```

It keeps on going and doesn't stop... Am I in over my head or do I just resolve one error at a time? Maybe there's some serious incompatibility with developing in VS 2012 and deploying it in IIS8.0 2012 MS Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this by just dealing one error at a time. It was mostly the connectionstring issue.

I had to use `<clear />` then fixed my `connectionstring` to support sql server 2000.

Comment: Wow, sql server 2000. Lol